# Rails db relations: Post.category.name = ? (undefined method `name')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Every post has only one category, and i need to access category's name by something like

```
p = Post.new
p.category.name = "tech"
p.save
```

How to do that?

---

```
   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy

       attr_accessible :name, :image

    end
```

Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    attr_accessible :category_id, :name, :text, :lang, :image

end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "image"
  end
```

Comment: I assume there is a db field `name` for `Category`?

Comment: Always provide the full error message please, the fact that it is probably "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" is much more revealing than just "undefined method".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example contains a problem.

```
p = Post.new
p.category.name = "tech"
p.save
```

First, you create a new post. Second, you want to assign a name to the category of the post, BUT there is no category assigned. This results in a call like `post.nil.name` where `nil` would be the category object, if assigned, which isn't the case. Since `nil` has no method `name`, you get the described error `undefined method name for nil class`.

To solve this, you first need to assign a category to work on.

`p.category = Category.first` or `p.category_id = 1`. After that, `p.category` will return the category object, therefore `p.category.name` is valid then because it is called on a category object and not on `nil`.

**tl;dr:**

```
p = Post.new
p.category # => nil
p.category.name # throws an error

p.category = Category.first
p.category # => <#Category ...>
p.category.name # => 'actual name of category'
p.category.name = 'foo' # works now
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need/want to explicitly build the category record if it doesn't exist.

To solve the problem, I'd think about creating a `category_name=` method in Post:

A `category_name=` settor would also take care of the ["law of Demeter"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) issue

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :category_id, :name, :text, :lang, :image

  attr_accessible :category_name=, :category_name

  def category_name=(name)
    self.category = Category.find_or_create_by_name(name)
  end

  def category_name
    category && category.name
  end
```

end

See also "Association Extensions" in the [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) docs for another way to do this.

Comment: Rails don't have a native method for do this??

Comment: yes it has, you defined `:belongs_to :category` therefore you get setters and getters for this. And `.build` does not autosave, it just assigns the category to the `Post` collection.

Comment: But the initial nil case is not covered by the default setter. That's the whole issue!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the setter, it is a design-/application-logic issue. `Category` has a `name` getter/setter. If there is no category given, there obviously is no setter/getter. Doing `post.category` covers what it should: assign a category object to the current post. If he wants to autocreate categories, your solution may be good. But as far as I can tell, this is not his intention.

Comment: Of course he wants to auto-create the category look at his question.... your interpretation is that he doesn't, mine is that he does....

Comment: @OP: if you want your app to know about the association between the post and its category then the settor is built-in **via the association**. But if you want the category_name to be an "automagic" attribute of the post then you need to do something like the `category_name` and `category_name=` methods that I show. See the Law of Demeter for more on this.